# Running Blender via Python

Tags: python, external-applications

I'm learning blender and want to create my own module with a custom UI. I'm stuck at the gate just trying to import Blender to run through independent python scripts:

```
import subprocess

bPath = "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe"

subprocess.run([bPath, "--background", "--python", "myScript.py"])
```

All that's in myScript.py for testing is:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
```

All I want to do first is load up a blender render window from Python that makes the cube, ideally one stripped of the interface. I can figure the rest out from there.

My error is

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This suggests there is a problem with the path to something in your script. I think you may need to give the absolute filepath to your `myScript.py` file.

Also, the "\" is an escape character in python, so if you're going to use it in the filepath to something, then you should use one of these methods:

```
bPath = r"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe"
```

or

```
bPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\blender.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my noob mistake. Is there a way to get blender to create a viewport this way?

Comment: Opening blender with the "--background" flag means you're opening blender without a UI. From what you've said, it sounds like what you want to do is make an Addon. I recommend downloading someone else's well-made addon and having a look at their code and reading [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_65_5/info_tutorial_addon.html) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get a blender window to show up with the cube added. I will sort the rest out from here.